# Debian apt-get upgrade How to install only security updates?

Tags: debian, apt

How to install only security updates in Debian? When I run apt-get upgrade, apt will offer all updates.

Comment: This question really belongs on either [SF] ([answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/270260/how-do-you-use-apt-get-to-only-install-critical-security-updates-on-ubuntu)) or [SU]. It well [applies to Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/194/20358), also.

Comment: Is a Linux question, is answered and belongs to [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394438/linux-display-or-upgrade-security-updates-only-using-apt).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Debsecan](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=debsecan) (Debian Security Analyzer) is better for manual upgrade and it can produce clear output. There are CVEs for detail information too. At first install debsecan:

```
sudo apt-get install debsecan
```

Get your distribution codename of Debian. For example:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

And now install all security updates (instead of *buster* choose your suite  detected from previous command. Values can be 'woody', 'sarge', 'etch', 'lenny', 'squeeze', 'wheezy', 'jessie', 'stretch', 'buster', 'bullseye' ... etc):

```
sudo apt-get install $(debsecan --suite buster --format packages --only-fixed)
```

---

All CVEs can be listed before the upgrade (use *--format detail* for detailed output):

```
debsecan
```

for example part of summary output:

[image: debsecan summary output]

Comment: This answer would be useful [here](http://serverfault.com/q/270260/85654), where it will get more attention.

Comment: This package does not appear to be maintained for Ubuntu, as it lacks suites for Ubuntu's releases, so I'm not sure it's useful there.

Comment: wow 66MB for an updater?

Answer (score 5):

The package [unattended-upgrades](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=unattended-upgrades) installs only security upgrades by default. You can configure it to install them automatically, or just call it with:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade
```

More information on how to get it running properly: https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Answer (score -1):

```
upgrade_repo() {
sudo apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/$1" \
-o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"    
}
```

Comment: Can you give some explanations?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Here's a [similar answer with a better explanation](http://serverfault.com/a/282518/85654).